# If A is measurable, there exist F $\subset$ A and open set G s.t. A $\subset$ G s.t. $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\lambda (G\setminus F) < \epsilon$.

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Why my logic is flawed in this reasoning:-

If A is measurable we have Sup $\lambda (F)$ = inf $\lambda (G)$ for all such G and F, therefore we can always find such F and G which are $\epsilon$ / 2 close to $\lambda (A)$.

Comment: What sort of set is $F$ supposed to be? My guess is compact, but that's just a guess until you say so. Why do you say there is a flaw in your reasoning? _Gven_ $\epsilon>0$ what you say is exactly right. Now, in the title you say "there exist $F$ and $G$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$...", which is simply wrong; what's true is that "for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $F$ and $G$ such that...".  I have no idea whether that answers your question, because it's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: Oops. Exactly right for sets of finite measure, that is.

Answer (score 1):

The way you stated the problem, $F$ and $G$ are not allowed to depend on $\epsilon$; in fact, $\forall ε>0, λ(G ∖ F) < ε$ implies $\lambda(G ∖ F) = 0$.  That can't be true: for example, if $A = \{ 0 \}$ any open set containing $A$ has to have strictly positive measure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, consider $R-Q$ where $Q$ is the set of rational numbers.